# I get a message about credentials when I try to log into a team Stack Overflow site

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

[image: This credential is already associated to a different account. Please use a different credential or log in as the credential owner.]

I've no idea what to do here. Thoughts?

Comment: It seems to think you're trying to create a new account instead of using an existing one. What does the login for Teams look like? Is there a create account button near the login button that you might be clicking on accident? Or maybe you're using a password manager that's auto-filling and submitting the wrong form?

Comment: @BSMP I reposted the question with better details over here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354692/can-i-merge-a-corporate-team-so-account-with-my-personal-so-account. Further, I looked at a million different tabs in my account but could not find this post, so I thought I forgot to submit it which is why I reposted. Anyway a better question is at that link.